# Adding two different dates in VB.net, without using 'Now'

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have been looking through a bunch of different posts on here and on other sites for adding two dates together, but for some reason everyone wants to use 'Now'

I would like to know how to add two different dates together when neither of which are now!

I have tried a few things but I am getting casting errors. Also worth noting I am setting it to the value of a dateTime picker on my page.

```
MaxDate.Value = MinDate.Value + TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
'does not work 
MaxDate.Value = Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
'does work!
```

If it is not obvious, I have two date pickers on my page and when a radio button is clicked I want to set the 'End date' (maxdate.value) to whatever the 'Start date' (mindate.value) is, and add one day to it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried to convert MinDate.Value to timestamp first, and then tried to add the second date?

Comment: Thank you, that does work....it just does not looking very clean having to do that in two lines. But as long as it works!

Comment: Not sure what kind of DateTimePicker you are using but it sure sounds like a borken one.  MinDate is a property of type DateTime, just like Now.  Be sure to use the .NET version and not some ancient ActiveX wrapper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do this:

```
MaxDate.Value = MidDate.Value.AddDays(1)
```

You don't need create a `TimeSpan` object for that because the `Date` type has built-in methods for doing incrementation by day, month, year, minute, etc.

The `AddDays` method does not alter the original date, it just returns a new `Date` object with the offset value.

By the way, if you want to subtract a day, there is no `MinusDays` method, just do `x.AddDays(-1)`.

Comment: Thanks! (it won't let me accept this as the answer for a few mins but i will) - This didn't show up in my intelisense!